# Google Sheets, rearrange data to new rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Second (and hopefully last) google sheets question today and forever.
As I am importing my data from a management system to another via google sheets, I am having some difficulty in following the new system's method of importing data.
So currently my sheet looks like this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID | First Name | Email Address | Phone | Email ID (Email IDs) | Number (Contact Numbers) | Is Primary (Email IDs) | Is Primary Phone (Contact Numbers) | Is Primary Mobile (Contact Numbers) | Mobile No | Company Name | Link Document Type (Links) | Link Name (Links) | Link Title (Links) |
| 2 | FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . | FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . | HIDDEN@hotmail.com | 971 2 1234567 | HIDDEN@hotmail.com |  | 1 |  |  | 971 50 12345678 | 1 FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . | Customer | 1 FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . | 1 FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . |

What I want to do is have numbers on column D and J to show at F (second number would be on a new row)
So the end result would look like this

|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** | **E** | **F** | **G** | **H** | **I** | **J** | **K** | **L** | **M** | **N** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **ID** | **First Name** | **Email Address** | **Phone** | **Email ID (Email IDs)** | **Number (Contact Numbers)** | **Is Primary (Email IDs)** | **Is Primary Phone (Contact Numbers)** | **Is Primary Mobile (Contact Numbers)** | **Mobile No** | **Company Name** | **Link Document Type (Links)** | **Link Name (Links)** | **Link Title (Links)** |
| **2** | FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . | FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . | HIDDEN@hotmail.com | 971 2 1234567 | HIDDEN@hotmail.com | 971 50 12345678 (From J) | 1 |  |  | 971 50 12345678 | 1 FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . | Customer | 1 FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . | 1 FERTICLINIC HOME CARE CENTRE L.L.C . |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  | 971 2 1234567 (From D) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

So basically the script would copy data from "J" to "F" then make a new row and copy data from "D" to "F" on the new row.

I hope this makes sense, any assistance is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a sample sheet? Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set the source and destination sheet names.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the source sheet name.
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Please set the destination sheet name.

  var [, ...values] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var res = values.flatMap(r => {
    r[5] = r[9];
    var temp = Array(r.length).fill(null);
    temp[5] = r[3];
    return [r, temp];
  });
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- When this script is run, each row is put as 2 rows. The value of column "J" is put to the column "F". And, the value of column "D" is put to the column "F".

#### Reference:

- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Answer (score 0):

#### Remapping

```
function remap() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hA,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let vo = [];
  vs.forEach(([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]) => {
    let o = [];
    if(d) {
      vo.push([a,b,c,d,e,d,g,h,i,j,k,l]);
    }
    if(j) {
      vo.push(['','','','','',j,'','','','','','']);
    }
  });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vo))
  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1,1,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you think about such a solution?

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A2:N2;"select J, D"))
```

paste into column F

[image]

you just have to enable iterative calculation in the settings.

File> Settings> Calculation> Iterative Calculation Enable this option and save